# symfony2 test case request cookie

Tags: symfony, phpunit

In my test, I'd like to specify a cookie to go along with the request.  I traced the code back to see how a cookie jar is used in the Client's __construct.  Though a var_dump here and a var_dump on the server side show no cookie being sent with the request.  I also tried sending a simpler string with HTTP_COOKIE as shown.

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;
use Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Cookie;
use Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\CookieJar;
class DefaultControllerTest extends WebTestCase {
    public function test() {
        $jar = new CookieJar();
        $cookie = new Cookie('locale2', 'fr', time() + 3600 * 24 * 7, '/', null, false, false);
        $jar->set($cookie);
        $client = static::createClient(array(), array(), $jar);  //this doesn't seem to attach cookies as expected!
        $crawler = $client->request(
            'GET', //method
            '/', //uri
            array(), //parameters
            array(), //files
            array(
                'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE' => 'en_US',
                //'HTTP_COOKIE' => 'locale2=fr' //this doesn't work either!
            ) //server
        );

        var_dump($client->getRequest());
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to create an object like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8432281/symfony2-read-cookie) with `$this->get('request');` or creating something like `$response = new RedirectResponse($url); $response->headers->setCookie(new Cookie(...` ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have an error in code:

```
$client = static::createClient(array(), array(), $jar); // Third parameter ?
```

Method `createClient` is defined as following (for Symfony 2.0.0):

```
static protected function createClient(array $options = array(), array $server = array())
```

So, it takes only two parameters and there is no place for cookie, because `createClient` method takes an instance of client from the test container:

```
$client = static::$kernel->getContainer()->get('test.client');
$client->setServerParameters($server);

return $client;
```

Here is a definition for the `test.client` service:

```
<service id="test.client" class="%test.client.class%" scope="prototype">
    <argument type="service" id="kernel" />
    <argument>%test.client.parameters%</argument>
    <argument type="service" id="test.client.history" />
    <argument type="service" id="test.client.cookiejar" />
</service>

<service id="test.client.cookiejar" class="%test.client.cookiejar.class%" scope="prototype" />
```

Now we see, that cookie jar service is injected into `test.client` and have a scope `prototype` which means that new object will be created on each access to that service.

However `Client` class has a method `getCookieJar()` and you can use it to set specific cookies for request (not tested, but expected to work):

```
$client = static::createClient();
$cookie = new Cookie('locale2', 'fr', time() + 3600 * 24 * 7, '/', null, false, false);
$client->getCookieJar()->set($cookie);
```

Comment: A complete explanation!  The last code block worked like a charm.