# phpunit session symfony2

Tags: session, symfony, phpunit

who knows how to create a symfony2.1.x session for phpunit tests ?

i found this, but it`s not working:

```
$account = $this->em->getRepository('BaseBundle:Account');
$user = $account->findOneById('835d278dfb30');        
$container = $this->client->getContainer();

$token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, array('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY', 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUS'));
$this->client->getContainer()->get('security.context')->setToken($token);
$session = $this->client->getContainer()->get('session');
$session->set('_security_secured_area', serialize($token));
$session->save();
```

after this i tried to make a request to the account url, which is protected through symfony´s security area and it should me not redirect to the login page :(

Please help me, i tried a lot of stuff out there but nothing works.

Comment: I understood you're trying to write a functional test. You need to send a cookie with your request so that your application can recognise the user.

Comment: yes, that´s exatly what i want... can you give me an example of a working cookie ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10859321/symfony2-test-case-request-cookie and http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/testing.html#working-with-the-test-client

Answer (score 1):

you  can use Symfony session mock objects.

Link to  documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/session_testing.html

Comment: I’m sorry, but you call that documentation?

Comment: Olivier, check out my reply below.